# Reusing an AnimationController

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to start an animation every time I double tab an image. My code works for the first double tab, but stops working for the next double tabs for some reason. My code looks like this:
`

```
child: new GestureDetector(
   onDoubleTap: () {
    _controller.forward();
  },
  child: ...
}
```

I'm creating and disposing the `AnimationController` like this:

```
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      vsync: this,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

I feel like it should work, what am I not seeing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try passing a `from` parameter of `0.0` to the `forward` method.

Comment: That works. So what happens when you don't pass in the `from` parameter and why doesn't it work?

Comment: The controller is already at 1.0 and can't go forward any further.

Comment: returns `'TickerFuture' is not a subtype of type 'AnimationController'`